# Validation errors when SQL query is formatted correctly

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to display the SQL correctly in my .aspx pages. But am getting a bunch of validation errors when I do. The code still appears to function correctly when running the page though. Here is what I mean:

[image]

If I had all of the SQL on one line then it works fine. When I try to format it correctly I am getting validation errors. How can I not get validation errors but display the query correctly?

This issue only seems to come up on longer queries.

Comment: why don't you do this as sproc?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SelectCommand` in the codebehind and use an `@` infront of a string ([Literal String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)), but cannot be used in the xHTML.

```
SqlDataSource6.SelectCommand = @"
    /* SQL Query Here */
";
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But I am on the asp side not the C# side.